# Temperature (white balance) in OpenColorIO

Tags: colors

I do not know how to continue in OpenColorIO to change the temperature (and tint). The temperature is a value between 1000 K and 16000 K by a neutral (default) value of 6500 K. I converted this value to a xyY value. How to continue with OCIO and XYZ color space?

Answer (score 0):

OpenColorIO, as of version 2.1, does not provide a way to change colour temperature, you would need to generate a set of MatrixTransform for the cases you need to handle, e.g. 3200K -> 6500K, 5500K -> 6500K, etc…